# Horizontal scrollbar for the contents in the iframe loaded in a cshtml

Tags: iframe, scrollbar

I am not able to provide a horizontal scrollbar for the html form which gets loaded within an iframe which itself is loaded inside a cshtml page.
Tried the below things:

1. Tried adding overflow : auto property to the iframe tag
2. Tried adding overflow : auto property to the div tag which has the iframe inside it(this does provide the horizontal scrollbar but not for the html contents of the iframe)
3. Tried adding `scrolling="Yes"` property to the iframe tag

also tried adding the overflow property in the inline css.

```
 <div id="iframe_container" class="col-lg-9" style="position: fixed; height:85%; width:93%; background: white;margin-top:60px">
                <iframe name="ifr" src="@ViewBag.formName" id="frmhtmlForms" scrolling="yes" style="position: absolute; height:100%; width:100%;" align="middle" onload="document.body.style.height = frames.ifr.document.body.offsetHeight + parseInt(document.getElementById('iframe_container').style.top) + parseInt(document.getElementById('iframe_container').style.bottom) + 'px'"></iframe>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please paste some code _in your post_ so someone can help you.

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

SO is a platform where you can get a good suggestion regarding your problems.  But for that, you need to be more specific about what you are asking?  what have you done so far?  Before asking please see the suggested SO question and take a look at them. Still, you did not find a solution then you can ask a question here.

Comment: I know i have to check the suggested SO questions before posting. I did check for the existing solutions but nothing worked!